# Spring rest call not working

Tags: rest

I had written a very small rest service. When I am trying through the rest cilent, I am getting the error as "method not supported". Can anybody, please suggest me on this.

```
**controller class**
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/movie")
public class MovieController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/{name}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes="application/json")

    public @ResponseBody Student getMovie(@PathVariable String name, ModelMap model, @RequestBody Student student, HttpSession session) {

         Map<Integer, Student> empData = new HashMap<Integer, Student>();
         empData.put(1,  student);
         return student;

    }

}

**Request I am sending throught Rest DHC Client**

URL: http://localhost:8081/SpringMVC/movie/test   
method selected: PUT
Headers: Content-Type:application/json
Body: {
"userId":"21",
"firstName":"srinu",
"lastName":"nivas"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use only Jersey to do what you want.

My web.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>appName</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.appName.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.JSPTemplatesBasePath</param-name>
            <param-value>/Pages/</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex</param-name>
            <param-value>/(resources|(Pages))/.*</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And in the rest class i return a Viewable:

My rest class:

```
@GET
@Path("/PathToAccessPage")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public Viewable GetMyClassPage(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context UriInfo ui, @Context HttpHeaders hh) {
    try {           
        MyClass myClass = getMyClass(); 
        return new Viewable("/page", myClass);
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
        return new Viewable("/error", "Error processing request: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Hope you help!

Comment: With the http method "get", I am able to get the results. But while I am using POST / PUT with JSON, I am getting the problem, while trying to send the request with JSON content.

Comment: João Marcos: If you could share a jersey example with post/put with JSON request/response. That should be fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the solution. I didn't import the below two jars.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
```

As I am using spring MVC and as you can see in the above code, I am giving as consumes=application/json, I thought springMVC will take care of that. It's my mistake and also, I think the error which was renedered by spring, should be something specific to this. Anyway, got the solution. Thanks all for the help.